# Upload data through restful service

Tags: rest, post, upload

I want to write a RESTful web service for client to upload data.
The data format is JSON

But I don't know much about it,can you give some sample code in JAVA? include the code of service and client that could demonstrate me the whole process of data uploading.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is the [Jackson Tutorials](http://jackson.codehaus.org/Tutorial).  Then look at either [Jersey's JSON Support](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html) or [RESTeasy's JSON Support](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html/json.html) depending on which framework you happen to be using.  *Data uploading* is a open-ended topic since there are a number of different ways that it can be accomplished.  If you POST JSON directly to the service then you can use JAXRS annotations like:

```java
@Path("/myservice")
public class MyService {
    @POST @Consumes("application/mytype+json")
    public Response processPostRequest (JsonBeanType postData) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The `processPostRequest` method will be invoked whenever a client POSTs data that includes the `Content-Type: application/mytype+json` HTTP header to the `/myservice` resource.

Another way to *upload* data is to send it using an HTML form.  There are a bunch of examples of processing HTML forms in Java.  The SO question [How can I handle multipart form data post requests in my Java servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510788/how-can-i-handle-multipart-form-data-post-requests-in-my-java-servlet) should start you off in the right direction.