# What to do in my Servlet, on the server side, to handle a Multipart POST?

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload, multipart

Maybe my question is redundant with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510788/how-can-i-handle-multipart-form-data-post-requests-in-my-java-servlet), but I can't find out how to handle a multipart HTTP request.

I wrote an HTTP request which use POST to send a file and a string. How to obtain both on server side in my Servlet ?

Here is what I did. Am I on the right way ?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Status status = new Status();

    boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
    if(isMultipart){
        status.setSuccess(true);
        status.setDescription("It is OK.");
        DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        factory.setSizeThreshold(MAX_MEMORY_SIZED);
        factory.setRepository(new File(ADRESS_WHERE_I_WANT_TO_PUT_THE_FILE));
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        upload.setSizeMax(MAX_FILE_SIZE_TO_BE_UPLOADED);
        try {
            List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator iter = items.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext()) { 

            ... // WHAT TO DO HERE TO GET MY STRING AND MY FILE ???

            }
    }
    else{
        status.setSuccess(false);
        status.setDescription("Not multipart.");
    }
    response.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    PrintWriter output = response.getWriter();
    output.write(gson.toJson(status));
    output.flush();
}
```

Comment: next to that answer there's also some library from apache that allows you to do exactly that kind of requests

Comment: But how do you do that ?

Comment: check these links out for multi threading and multi part in http apache http://evgenyg.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/uploading-files-multipart-post-apache/,  http://pro-programmers.blogspot.de/2009/06/apache-httpclient-multi-threads.html

Comment: Thanks anyway, I finally found out trying again and again !

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the [MultipartParser](http://www.servlets.com/cos/javadoc/com/oreilly/servlet/multipart/MultipartParser.html) available at [servlets.com](http://www.servlets.com/cos/)

From the website:

> There's no sense in reinventing the wheel--here are some servlet
>   support classes I wrote that you can use. Most famous is the file
>   upload package MultipartRequest and MultipartParser