# How to write server side File Receiver for a Multipart post

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, file-upload

I found the multi-part post on 
[Post multipart request with Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017414/post-multipart-request-with-android-sdk)

But now I need a server side to receive it. How do I do it?

Comment: How about searching for "Java file upload"?

Comment: Andrzej Doyle has suggested using Apache fileUpload (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3510818/32090)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [apache file upload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/).

Comment: First i was confused what Multipart post is. Finally I realised its the same thing that happens in a Form post. Tx